# Select a third column based on two distant rows within the same table

Tags: sql

I want to select a third column based on two distant columns within the same table.

I could only think of this:

```
select tl.thirdcolumn
from table1 t1
WHERE
EXISTS
(
    Select distinct tl.firstcolumn , t1.secondcolumn
    From t1
)
```

This:

```
select distinct tl.thirdcolumn
from table t1
```

won't work as I don't want the distinct thirdrow. I want the thirdrow to be based on the first two rows being distinct.

I guess its a kind of nested sql statment with a select top 1... idk

```
CATEGORY    NAME                             Query     
---------------------------------------------------
STUDENTS    NUMBER_OF_CHAPTERS               QueryA    
STUDENTS    NUMBER_OF_STUDENT_MEMBERS        QueryB    
STUDENTS    NUMBER_OF_STUDENT_MEMBERS        QueryB    
MEMBERS     NUMBER_OF_MEMBERS_WORLDWIDE      QueryC    
MEMBERS     NUMBER_OF_MEMBERS_WORLDWIDE      QueryC
```

Comment: What you show is column, not row. Did you mix them up? And some data would be helpful. Also what SQL variant is this, SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: Oh I ment column

Comment: You included an example of input data, what is your expected output?

Comment: are tl and t1 the same table? (looks like a typo)

Comment: Do you mean by `EXISTS` here if the `column` isn't `NULL`? If Yes, Wouldn't `WHERE t1.firstcolumn IS NOT NULL AND t1.secondcolumn IS NOT NULL GROUP BY t1.firstcolumn, t1.secondcolumn` be enough?

Comment: I am trying to grab the third column where the other two columns are distinct  columns

Comment: Can you put a sample of the Table on SQLFiddle with the result you expect from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather hard to follow, but I think you might simply want `group by`:

```
select tl.firstcolumn , t1.secondcolumn, max(tl.thirdcolumn)
from table1 t1
group by tl.firstcolumn , t1.secondcolumn;
```

If you want rows where the pair of values only appears once, then add `having count(*) = 1`:

```
select tl.firstcolumn , t1.secondcolumn, max(tl.thirdcolumn)
from table1 t1
group by tl.firstcolumn , t1.secondcolumn
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Query -

```
SELECT
    CATEGORY,NAME,QUERY
FROM
    (
        WITH TAB AS (
            SELECT
                'STUDENTS' AS CATEGORY,
                'NUMBER_OF_CHAPTERS' AS NAME,
                'QUERYA' AS QUERY
            FROM
                DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                'STUDENTS' AS CATEGORY,
                'NUMBER_OF_STUDENT_MEMBERS' AS NAME,
                'QUERYB' AS QUERY
            FROM
                DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                'STUDENTS' AS CATEGORY,
                'NUMBER_OF_STUDENT_MEMBERS' AS NAME,
                'QUERYB' AS QUERY
            FROM
                DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                'MEMBERS' AS CATEGORY,
                'NUMBER_OF_MEMBERS_WORLDWIDE' AS NAME,
                'QUERYC' AS QUERY
            FROM
                DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                'MEMBERS' AS CATEGORY,
                'NUMBER_OF_MEMBERS_WORLDWIDE' AS NAME,
                'QUERYC' AS QUERY
            FROM
                DUAL
        ) SELECT
            CATEGORY,
            NAME,
            QUERY,
            COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY
                CATEGORY,
                NAME
                ORDER BY
                    CATEGORY,
                    NAME,
                    QUERY
            ) AS RNK
        FROM
            TAB
    )
WHERE
    RNK   = 1;
```

> Output -

```
"CATEGORY","NAME","QUERY"
"STUDENTS","NUMBER_OF_CHAPTERS","QueryA"
```